# Salto de linea no funciona en alert como respuesta de ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el envío de los datos de un formulario mediante `AJAX` y se regresa un string como respuesta, pero los saltos de linea de la respuesta no se muestran correctamente y desconozco la razón.
He intentado con `\n`, `\\n` y `<br>`, pero ninguno funciona.

```js
$.ajax({
                       url: "evSeg2_1.php",
                       type: "POST",
                       data: datos,
                       processData: false,  
                       contentType: false,   
                       beforeSend: function(){
                           $('#loading').show();
                           $('.continuar').attr('disabled','disabled');
                       },
                       complete: function(){
                           $('#loading').hide();
                           $('.continuar').removeAttr('disabled');
                       },
                       success: function(resp){
                           alert(resp);
                           //$(location).attr('href','../index.php');
                           
                       },
                       error: function(){
                           alert('Error al enviar formulario.');
                       }
                     });
```

[image: Muestra fallo salto de linea]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El caracter `\n` te debería de funcionar. ¿Qué por qué no te funciona a ti? Deberíamos ver lo que te devuelve el servidor en la llamada AJAX.

```js
let frase = 'Buenos días Stackoverflow \n ¿Cómo estáis';
alert (frase);
```

No obstante, mi recomendación es que no comuniques con la función `alert()`, hay librerías de sencillo uso que están hechas para este tipo de mensajes y te permiten mayor flexibilidad y un mejor diseño de lo que muestras. Un ejemplo con Sweetalert2:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Evaluación creada',
  html: "CORTE DE CAMINO ingresado <br> DISTANCIA DE SEGURIDAD ingresado <br> TÉCNICA DE VOLTEO ingresado",
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```